# How to activate and deactivate a function using a checkbutton?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I would like to activate and deactivate a method for selecting a region of interest (ROI) of an image by pressing a button. I used a checkbutton which returns `1` or `0` if it is pressed or not. The function that should be turned on or off is matplotlibs [RectangleSelector](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector). So far pressing the `ROI` button doesn't do anything at all.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from numpy.random import rand
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector

root = Tk.Tk()
root_panel = Tk.Frame(root)
root_panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
img = ax.imshow(rand(10, 5), extent=(1, 2, 1, 2), picker=True)
ax.axis([0, 3, 0, 3])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# ROI BUTTON
switch_variable = Tk.IntVar()
ROIBtn = Tk.Checkbutton(master=root_panel, text='ROI', indicatoron=False, 
variable=switch_variable)
ROIBtn.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

def onselect(eclick, erelease):
    global switch_variable
    if switch_variable.get() == 1:
        x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
        x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
        global roi
        roi = (x1,y1,x2,y2)
        roi = list(map(int, roi))
        global cropped
        cropped = img[int(roi[1]):int(roi[3]), int(roi[0]):int(roi[2])]
        ax.clear
        ax.imshow(cropped)
        fig.canvas.draw()

def toggle_selector(event):
    global switch_variable
    if switch_variable.get() == 1:
        if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
            print('RectangleSelector deactivated.')
            toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
        if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
            print('RectangleSelector activated.')
            toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)

if switch_variable.get() == 1:
    toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax, onselect, drawtype='box')
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)

root.mainloop()
```

What I would like to know is how do I use `switch_variable` to tell my program when to use `onselect` and when it should do nothing. Thanks!

Comment: You can assign a function to `command` option of `ROIBtn`.  The function will be called whenever you click the button.

Comment: @acw1668 `Checkbutton` has no option `command`. Only `Button` does but this is not what I want to use

Comment: it does. [http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)

Comment: Another way is to register a callback on the `switch_variable`: `switch_variable.trace("w", callback)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have copied part of your code exactly from [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector) without understanding what the different parts do. The `toggle_selector` function does exactly what you want to do, but you need to run it at the right time and you need to check for the condition you want.

the first thing you need to understand is that everything that is not in a function will be executed only once, when the GUI is initiated. Because `switch_variable` is initiated with value `0`, your code will skip over the `if switch_variable.get() == 1:` piece of code and it will never be re-evaluated.

You need the `toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax, onselect, drawtype='box')`, to initiate the `RectangleSelector`, but you don't need the `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)` because you don't want to bind anything to a keypress, you want to bind to the checkbutton being clicked.
You can do that in two ways, either with `command=toggle_selector` in your `CheckButton` (keep in mind that you need to define the function before the Checkbutton in this case) or by tracing the variable like `switch_variable.trace("w", toggle_selector)`.

Then, in the `toggle_selector` function, there's a check for `event.key in ['Q', 'q']`. This makes no sense in this case, it is used in the code example because that lets you switch the function on and off with the `q` and `a` keys, but you don't want this. The only thing you need to check for is whether the `switch_variable` holds value `1` or `0`.

Putting that all together it becomes:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from numpy.random import rand
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector

def onselect(eclick, erelease):
    if switch_variable.get() == 1:
        x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
        x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
        roi = (x1,y1,x2,y2)
        roi = list(map(int, roi))
        cropped = img[int(roi[1]):int(roi[3]), int(roi[0]):int(roi[2])]
        ax.clear
        ax.imshow(cropped)
        fig.canvas.draw()

def toggle_selector(*args):
    if switch_variable.get() == 0:
        print('RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    elif switch_variable.get() == 1:
        print('RectangleSelector activated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)

root = Tk.Tk()
root_panel = Tk.Frame(root)
root_panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rand_img = rand(10, 5)
img = ax.imshow(rand_img, extent=(1, 2, 1, 2), picker=True)
ax.axis([0, 3, 0, 3])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# ROI BUTTON
switch_variable = Tk.IntVar()
ROIBtn = Tk.Checkbutton(master=root_panel, text='ROI', indicatoron=False, variable=switch_variable, command=toggle_selector)
ROIBtn.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax, onselect, drawtype='box')
toggle_selector()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `toggle_selector()` is already used to enable/disable the `RectangleSelector` based on key pressed, it can be used by `command` option of `ROIBtn` as well.

Below is a modified code based on yours:

```
import sys
try:
    import Tkinter as Tk
except:
    import tkinter as Tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from numpy.random import rand
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector

root = Tk.Tk()
root_panel = Tk.Frame(root)
root_panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
img = ax.imshow(rand(10, 5), extent=(1, 2, 1, 2), picker=True)
ax.axis([0, 3, 0, 3])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def onselect(eclick, erelease):
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    try:
        cropped = img[y1:y2, x1:x2] # this raises TypeError: 'AxesImage' object is not subscriptable
        ax.clear()
        ax.imshow(cropped)
        fig.canvas.draw()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error:', e)

# must set default value of event argument,
# otherwise problem when triggered by ROIBtn
def toggle_selector(event=None):
    #print('toggle_selector:', event.key if event else switch_variable.get())
    active = None
    if event:
        # triggered by keypressed
        if event.key in 'Qq':
            if selector.active: active = 0
        elif event.key in 'Aa':
            if not selector.active: active = 1
    else:
        # triggered by ROIBtn
        active = switch_variable.get()
    if active is not None:
        switch_variable.set(active) # update ROIBtn
        selector.set_active(active == 1)
        print('RectangleSelector {}activated.'.format('' if active == 1 else 'de'))

# ROI BUTTON
switch_variable = Tk.IntVar()
# set command option to toggle_selector()
ROIBtn = Tk.Checkbutton(master=root_panel, text='ROI', indicatoron=False, variable=switch_variable, command=toggle_selector)
ROIBtn.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

selector = RectangleSelector(ax, onselect, drawtype='box')
selector.set_active(switch_variable.get())
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)

root.mainloop()
```